# Getting variable value out of addEventListener

Tags: javascript, click, addeventlistener

How can I update the value of of the variable "clicked" after the function "clickListener" runs? It's definitely an issue with the "clicked" variable's scope.

```
var clicked = 'no';
focus();
listener = addEventListener('blur', clickListener);
function clickListener(){
    if(document.activeElement == document.getElementById('someIframe')){
        clicked = 'yes';
        console.log(clicked);
    }
};
```

Whenever I run this, console logs "yes" but the "outter" clicked is still no if I check the variable after the click happens.

---

Here is a JSFiddle of my issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/6c3nbpk5/4/

1. Open Console
2. Note state of DIV "message" ('not clicked')
3. Click in the iframe where it says "click me"
4. Note that console shows 'Div Message: Clicked'
5. Note variable within function should be updated to clicked confirmed by console
6. Note Div "message" still displays not clicked.

I need divMessage to update to clicked. However, All of this is within a function tracking multiple iframes so I can not append the variable to the window.

Comment: Your "click" listener isn't bound to the click event. But anyway, how do you check the variable after the event?

Comment: Try replacing all `clicked` with `window.clicked` and see what happens

Comment: It is because I am checking the click of an iframe. One can't assign a click listener to an iframe so instead I am looking for the last element in focus before the a new tab opens up after clicking the iframe.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is function scoped, if it doesn't find a definition in the current function scope, it will check the outer scope and so on.

You are in fact changing the value of the outer `clicked` in your inner function.

However it might seem a bit tricky - see here to get a feel for the timing - https://jsfiddle.net/6c3nbpk5/1/.

```
var clicked = 'no';
window.addEventListener('click', clickListener);
function clickListener(){
        clicked = 'yes';
        window.alert(clicked);
};
window.alert(clicked);
```

Comment: Thank you. Please see question for updated jsfiddle of my problem.

Comment: you have a **blur** event on **window**, what you want is a **click** event on your **iframe**.  Please mark as answer or let me know what you don't understand.

Comment: You can not register click events on cross domain iframes. The iframe in my jsfiddle is not crossdomain for the demo but on my project it is cross domain. Therefore, a click listener will not work. However, my question has nothing to do with the event listener. It has to do with getting the value of "clicked" outside the function. Please see my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6c3nbpk5/4/ I want the text string 'not clicked' to change to 'clicked'.

Answer (score 0):

`addEventListener` is a function that must be called from an event target. You should not be setting it equal to anything.

For example, let's say you have a div an you want to store a variable that determines if it has been clicked:

```
var div = document.querySelector('div'); // grabs the first div
var clicked = false;

div.addEventListener('click', function() {
  clicked = true;
});
```

**Note:** What your code is currently doing is registering an event listener on `window` since you did not specify a target, javascript assumes you mean `window`.

As such, any blur event on the page will fire your callback. If this is the intended behavior, please post your full html, with a more specific explanation of what you are trying to achieve and we can help debug that issue.

It would seem to me that you should be using a click event rather than a blur event, as it is just beating around the bush to get the same result.